# A random number automatically appended to a js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

My index.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("body").load("AJAX.php");
});</script></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And my AJAX.php code

```
<body>
<script src="js/asdf.js"></script>

</body>
```

and my asdf.js code

```
function cool(){
    alert("hi");}
```

Now When i load index.php and see the console it output

`[16:21:57.237] GET http://localhost/js/asdf.js?_=1342003917230 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 8ms]`

Now i want to know why it is adding that random number to url of js file and how to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is added to prevent the file from being served from browser cache.

If you are using the .load method in jQuery you can disable it by passing the option `{cache:false}`

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache : true});
$.load(url, data, function() {
    // callback function
});
```

Or

```
$.ajax(url, {cache : true, dataType : 'html', success : function (response) {
    $('body').html(response);
}});
```

Comment: where to put that line {cache:false}

Comment: You can use `$.ajaxSetup` to enable caching globally. Or else you will have to use `$.ajax`

Comment: Sorry...It is cache:true, my mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

See [the docs for the ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> `cache`
>
> Default: `true`, `false` for `dataType` 'script' and 'jsonp'
>
> If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter,
>   "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

Comment: instead of giving me link , may you give me the solution in code

Comment: @Random — The solution is in the quoted material. Set the cache option to true.

Comment: Since the original code is using `.load`, which uses the `html` data type internally, `cache` should already be `true` though...